# Two GlassFish installs on one computer

Tags: glassfish

I want to install two GlassFish servers, each serving on different ports, on one Windows Server OS. 
Is this possible>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible.

Comment: bit of a nightmare though, need to move all the catalina ports, or bind each to a different ip.

Answer (score 1):

you can set up glassfish in different port with IIS. you run the glassfish admin console, and go to the network listener in the left side of admin GUI. Default port content three port, 4848, 8181, and 8080. You can add new Listener here such as [newport]and your application become http://localhost:[newport]/yourApp

Perhaps this is can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I run with several instances, in Solaris, on the same system, so I think it will work on Windows as well.

You might need to carefully map out port utilization, by making the second instance use all non-default ports, or by running with multiple IP addresses, and binding each GF instance to its own IP.